# how to select an element in a list of element using selenium webdriver?

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

How to select abc from the list?

[image: list select]

Comment: did you try with simple clicking using click() method

Comment: which language do you use and what is your html?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SelectElement.

Example:

```
Select foo = new Select(Driver.findElement(By.id("foo")));
foo.selectByVisibleText("abc");
```

Comment: Element should have been "select" but was "div" :Exception is coming

Comment: Then you should first click on the div, then wait until the element you want to click to be displayed. That should work.